# Getting (quickly) a String from an array of String

Tags: java, string, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to convert an ArrayList to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string)

I have an ArrayList in my class.

I need to make a String composed of all those Strings (I know, why not use a String in the first place - I'm dealing with amazing legacy code there and my hands are tied).

Is there a quickier way than something like :

```
String total;
for (String s : list)
{
   total += s;
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Probably is ; didn't see this one when I searched. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that that question is pretty old - I've just added an answer there myself pointing to a rather newer library. There's certainly no need to code this yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use a StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for ( String st: list ) {
    sb.append(st);
}
String total = sb.toString();
```

This is not shorter code, but faster, as it prevents the massive amount of Object creation when using String concatenation (and thus in many cases lots of Garbage Collections).

Comment: The problem in the variant in the question is more the repeated copying of the internal `char[]` than the creating of new `String` objects.