# Retrieve Arraylist to String Variable

Tags: android, string, arraylist

I have arraylist  "**myorderdata**". I want to retrieve this arraylist to one String variable  and want "," separator between each value retrieve from array list .

I have tried to do this with 
`String[] y = myorderdata.toArray(new String[0]);` but this doesn't work .
Can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/599181/593709)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for( String string : myorderdata )
    {
        sb.append( string );
        sb.append( "," );           
    }
    sb.deleteCharAt( sb.length() );

    String result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another variation to solve this task. Android offers two util methods to join the elements of an array or an Iterable in the class [TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable%29).

```
// Join the elements of myorderdata and separate them with a comma:
String joinedString = TextUtils.join(",", myorderdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method to join arrays:

```
//for List of strings
public static String join(List<String> listStrings, String separator) {
  String[] sl = (String[]) listStrings.toArray(new String[]{});

  return join(sl, separator);
}


/**
 * Joins an array of string with the given separator
 * @param strings array of string
 * @param separator string to join with
 * @return a single joined string from array 
 */
public static String join(String[] strings, String separator) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) sb.append(separator);
        sb.append(strings[i]);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: first of all i want to retrive data from array list to string

Comment: still, you need to use the same method, but first you need to get arrays out from your list. for e.g.: `foreach(String[] array : myorderdata){ String line = join(array, ","); }`