# How can convert ArrayList<Long> to String in Java (Android)?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to convert an ArrayList to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string)

I need your help! I have array of JSon (esponse from Facebook). ArrayList. How can convert this array to String? Thanks.

Comment: [Exact Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/599161/940096)

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for (Long l:list)
    sb.append(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

best way would be to iterate over `ArrayList` and build a `String`

```
ArrayList<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>(); 

String listString = ""; 

for (long l : list) 
{ 
    listString += String.valueOf(l) + "\n";
}
```

**UPDATE**
using `StringBuilder` is much better approach as Strings are immutable and everytime you append to `String` it creates new `String` in memory.
also

"+" operator is overloaded for `String` and used to concatenated two `String`. Internally "+" operation is implemented using either `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using StringBuilder class

```
public String ConvertArrayToString(Long[] longArray)
{
    if(longArray != null)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(longArray.length);         
        for(int i = 0; i < longArray.length; i++)
        {
            sb.append(longArray[i]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    return null;
}
```