# Compare List<String[]>

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

I have two `List<String[]>`'s (string array lists), and I'd like to match the contents with each other. Obviously `==` doesn't do the trick, but `.equals ()` doesn't seem to do it either. So how should I check whether the contents of the string array lists are the same?

By the way, in both above cases I got an exception with message `null`.

**EDIT:** Ok... for some reason only `x.equals(y)` works, and not `y.equals(x)`. Odd...

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of what you have tried?

Comment: "I got an exception with message **null** ... for some reason only x.equals (y) works, and **not y.equals (x)**." I believe `y` is `null`, do you ever initialize it?

Comment: +Sam I do, right after `public class MainActivity extends Activity {`.

Comment: Please post the relevant code, if you are receiving NullPointerExceptions then you are _defining_ but not _initializing_ something. (Also you'll want to use `@username` instead of `+username` in SO to notify a particular user.)

Comment: Where exactly are you getting a null exception? Maybe you need to make sure y is not null before y.equals(x). For example if(y!=null && y.equals(x) || y==null && x==null) { ...

Comment: Ok... I was about to accept the first answer... Only where the hell did that answer poof to?

Comment: Whoever mass-downvoted almost all answers, please explain your rational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `.equals()` works fine, but somehow only in one direction.

I was going to accept the first answer on this question, but apparently the guy removed his answer.

Comment: if it works in one direction its not working. you are creating a bug here that will haunt you later. both @Paul Bellora and my answer are fine stick with one of them

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the easiest solution would be to use two `List<List<String>>`s instead. Assuming the `List` implementations used extend `AbstractList`, using `equals` will give you the desired behavior. From the documentation for [`AbstractList.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns
>   `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists
>   have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
>   lists are *equal*. (Two elements `e1` and `e2` are equal if `(e1==null ?
>   e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`.) In other words, two lists are defined to
>   be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.

You can easily wrap a `String[]` in a thin `List<String>` implementation that extends `AbstractList` by using [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

**EDIT:** Here's an example:

```
String[] array1 = {"1", "2", "3"};
String[] array2 = {"4", "7"};

String[] array3 = {"1", "2", "3"};
String[] array4 = {"4", "7"};

List<List<String>> lst1 = new ArrayList<>();
lst1.add(Arrays.asList(array1));
lst1.add(Arrays.asList(array2));

List<List<String>> lst2 = new ArrayList<>();
lst2.add(Arrays.asList(array3));
lst2.add(Arrays.asList(array4));

System.out.println(lst1.equals(lst2)); //prints true
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically you should avoid dealing with Arrays. they are ugly and lead to these kind of problems. If possible use `List<List<String>>` then you can use `.equals()` normally.

if you insist, you could use a custom isequal implementation like below. the key is to use `Arrays.equals()`

```
public class DemoEquals {
    List<String[]> listOne = (List<String[]>) Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one1", "one2"}, new String[]{"two1"});
    List<String[]> listOneOne = (List<String[]>) Arrays.asList(new String[]{"one1", "one2"}, new String[]{"two1"});
    List<String[]> listTwo = (List<String[]>) Arrays.asList(new String[]{"2one1", "2one2"}, new String[]{"2two1"});

    private boolean isEqual(List<String[]> list1, List<String[]> list2) {
        if (list1.size() != list2.size()) return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            if (!Arrays.equals(list1.get(i), list2.get(i))) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void isEqual() {
        //prints true
        System.out.println(isEqual(Collections.EMPTY_LIST, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
        //prints true
        System.out.println(isEqual(listOne, listOne));
        //prints true
        System.out.println(isEqual(listOne, listOneOne));
        //prints false
        System.out.println(isEqual(listOne, listTwo));
        //prints false
        System.out.println(isEqual(listOne, Collections.EMPTY_LIST));

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DemoEquals().isEqual();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INTERFACE Comparable. Implement the needed method and you can use the List1.compare(List2) function.

Answer (score -1):

Using Jon Skeet's answer of [how to convert a List to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string) (using Guava), another option would be to convert the 2 lists to 2 strings and then compare them using `equals`.  No looping.