# Convert ArrayList to String

Tags: java, list

I have an `ArrayList` and I need to convert it to one String.

Each value in the String will be inside mark and will be separated by comma something like this:

```
ArrayList list = [a,b,c]

String s = " ’a’,’b’,’c’ ";
```

I am looking for efficient solution .

Comment: `I am looking for efficient solution ` -> First, do you know how to do it inefficiently?

Comment: @Roman: I think this is homework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to convert an ArrayList to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can follow these steps: -**

- Create an empty [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instance

  ```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  ```
- Iterate over your `list`
- For each element, append the representation of each element to your StringBuilder instance

  ```
  builder.append("'").append(eachElement).append("', ");
  ```
- Now, since there would be a last comma left, you need to remove that. You can use `StringBuilder.replace()` to remove the last character.

You can take a look at documentation of [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to know more about various methods you can use.

Comment: I really like your idea of getting rid of the one comma too many. I always do it with an if inside the loop, but your solution is more efficient.

Comment: @Zane. Well, why would you need an `if` for that? but that would be better to remove it forehand.

Comment: What's the point of using a `StringBuilder` if you still end up doing `append("'" + eachElement + "', ")`?

Comment: @adarshr. Isn't StringBuilder there for that purpose only?? To modify the existing string content?

Comment: @Rohit Adarshr's complaint is that the line should be replaced with 3 appends...  since you're doing String addition in the append, which is what you try to avoid by using a StringBuilder in the first place.

Comment: @BillJames. Ah! Man you're right. Sorry adarsh. will edit it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at StringBuilder and StringBuffer:

[StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

[StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an overkill here but providing a more functional approach through [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String ... args){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList(){{add("a");add("b");add("c");}};
        Collection<String> quotedList = Collections2.transform(list,new Function<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(String s) {
                return "'"+s+"'";
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Joiner.on(",").join(quotedList));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use StringUtils library from Apache org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

```
    StringUtils.join(list, ", ");
```

or

```
String s = (!list.isEmpty())? "'" + StringUtils.join(list , "', '")+ "'":null;
```