# retrieving data from sqlite: NullPointerException

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to retrieve data from database and display it on LOG, here my code:

```
 String dd = "1/23/2013";

  String sp = "Sky Storm";

 Log.d("Checking",db.getMeterNUmber2(dd,sp).toString());
```

And `getMeterNUmber2` are in DBAdapter and the data that im looking for are in database, so I just want to retrieve it.

My DB Adapter :

```
public ArrayList<String> getMeterNUmber2(String date , String Vname) throws SQLException {    

    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{date,Vname}; 

    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT MeterNumber FROM " + SCAN_TABLE + " WHERE  Date = ? AND VendorName = ? ",whereArgs);

    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (mcursor.moveToNext()) {
        results.add(mcursor.getString(0));
    }

    return results;

}
```

I'm getting error in logcat:

```
01-24 19:57:13.590: E/AndroidRuntime(11662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 19:57:13.590: E/AndroidRuntime(11662): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-24 19:57:13.590: E/AndroidRuntime(11662):    at scann.barcode.scan.DBAdapter.getMeterNUmber2(DBAdapter.java:303)
01-24 19:57:13.590: E/AndroidRuntime(11662):    at scann.barcode.scan.Result$1.onClick(Result.java:104)
```

Comment: I want to diplay on a LOGCAT

Comment: Not enough information to determine your problem. Where is the 'new' db created, where do you do a db.open, are you returning a cursor, etc.?

Comment: I just used this method to display data from database and using this two values for parameters, so if i put more code here it will make no sense for me, coz I now only this part.

Comment: you posted code that does not have the problem. post DBAdapter.getnumberBYDate() on line 303

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same problem as you and when i look at your log cat

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException ,
```

It returning null value , so that means It does not read into your Database,

please check if you have opened your database e.g : `db.open() and close`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't just log in logcat `ArrayList<String>` returned from `getMeterNUmber2` because it is a list. You need to retrieve single string values from there first: [Best way to convert an ArrayList to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string) .

Comment: I have used the same arrayList into another class and it working fine.