# How to convert from ArrayList to String?

Tags: string, arraylist

After compiling an ArrayList in java, how do I print it as a string?
Using `ArrayList.toString()` gives the values with brackets around them and commas between them.

I want to print them without brackets and only spaces between them.

Comment: Create your own utility method that takes ArrayList as a parameter.

Comment: <del>@Mayank Given that ArrayList is mentioned, probably Java</del> Edit: nevermind

Comment: Why not just do a for loop and print them out that way.

Comment: @JoeBo Are you asking whether or not a library function does this? It's not that difficult to just hand-roll your own.

Comment: @DennisMeng Not necessarily... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx

Comment: @DennisMeng C# has `ArrayList` too, and maybe couple other languages

Comment: @RyanHenderson Yeah, I googled right after I posted and realized my mistake.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to convert an ArrayList to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming Java)

You can write your own method to do that:

```java
public static <T> String listToString(List<T> list) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    boolean b = false;
    for (T o : list) {
        if (b)
            sb.append(' ');

        sb.append(o);
        b = true;
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Or, if you're using Guava, you can use [`Joiner`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html):

```java
Joiner.on(' ').join(list)
```

---

Similarly, if you *just* are interested in printing, you can avoid creating a new string all together:

```java
public static <T> void printList(List<T> list) {
    for (T o : list) {
        System.out.print(o);
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Depending on the type of list, `list.get(i)` could be linear-time. Why not use a for-each loop and a boolean flag?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections), you can use the `makeString()` method.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");

Assert.assertEquals(
    "one two three",
    ArrayListAdapter.adapt(list).makeString(" "));
```

If you can convert your `ArrayList` to a `FastList`, you can get rid of the adapter.

```
Assert.assertEquals(
    "one two three",
    FastList.newListWith("one", "two", "three").makeString(" "));
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 0):

for c#

```
string.Join(" ", _list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you're using, but try either:

```
ArrayList.join()
```

or

```
ArrayList.toArray().join()
```

Comment: Oh, and if you're trying to avoid having commas, use join("").

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++){
    System.out.print(arraylist.get(i).toString + " ");
}
```

???