# How to convert an array list stored in a recyclerview adapter to a string?

Tags: android, arraylist, type-conversion, android-recyclerview, stringbuilder

Not to a string array. I'm downloading movie reviews via AsyncTask and storing the list in an array in a Recyclerview Adapter. There's a toast message in the returnReviewData method in case the data is unavailable. I'd like to display a text message instead.

I know how to convert an ArrayList to a String using a String builder. However, I haven't been able to do it here(incl. like they do in the threads below). Is it possible to do it inside the if statement? Thank you in advance.

[Best way to convert an ArrayList to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string)

[how to convert arraylist into string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630385/how-to-convert-arraylist-into-string)

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MovieTrailerAdapter.MovieTrailerAdapterOnClickHandler, AsyncTaskReviewInterface {

//Tag for the log messages
    private static final String TAG = DetailActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ArrayList<MovieReview> simpleJsonMovieReviewData = new ArrayList<>();
 private Context context;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerViewReview;
 private MovieReviewAdapter movieReviewAdapter;
 Movie movie;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

   context = getApplicationContext();
        mRecyclerViewReview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_review);
   movieReviewAdapter = new MovieReviewAdapter(simpleJsonMovieReviewData, context);
      mRecyclerViewReview.setAdapter(movieReviewAdapter);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mReviewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerViewReview.setLayoutManager(mReviewLayoutManager);

 if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null)
        {
            movie = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Movie");
   movieId = movie.getMovieId();

            MovieReviewAsyncTask myReviewTask = new MovieReviewAsyncTask(this);
            myReviewTask.execute(movieId);
}

public void returnReviewData(ArrayList<MovieReview> simpleJsonMovieReviewData)
    {
        movieReviewAdapter = new MovieReviewAdapter(simpleJsonMovieReviewData, DetailActivity.this);
        mRecyclerViewReview.setAdapter(movieReviewAdapter);

        if (simpleJsonMovieReviewData.size() == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(DetailActivity.this, R.string.review_unavailable, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve. Converting an ArrayList to a string should work inside a RecyclerViewAdapter exactly like everywhere else in your code. Where does it fail?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann simpleJsonMovieReviewData can't be converted; setText doesn't work.I just want to display a message "Data currently unavailable" which will be displayed on screen.

Comment: @LeadBox4 check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27801394/3831557)

Comment: Ok, if I understand it correctly, you want to have some message in your UI, when no data is available. Then your current approach isn't ideal. Your RecyclerView expects a list of `MovieReview` objects. You can't just put a string in it. Instead, check out what your activity should do if your request doesn't return data here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217436/how-to-show-an-empty-view-with-a-recyclerview

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann So, I would set the TextView to invisible and then set it visible in the if statement? Just replace the toast message?

Comment: @LeadBox4 Almost. Don't use `invisible` here. Set the visibility to `gone` per default and make your RecyclerView `visible` if you get movie data. If you don't get data, set the visibility of your RecyclerView to `gone` and make your TextView `visible` in your `if` statement.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarelaThank you for the link. So, it's better to put the code in the adapter class? Then, I don't need to create a textview in xml?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmannDo I put the emptylist TextView in the activity xml or the list xml?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmannSolved! I did it like in the most accepted answer in the link you posted. Can you put that in an answer here so that I can give you points? Thank you.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela Thank you for the links.