# Array to string on Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, compiler-errors

I have a string array. I want to compare this string array with two string, so first i assigned array to variable then I compare this variable with strings.if array converted equals first string, do something else equals second, do something. But it raises `cannot resolve method toString` error.

```
String stopC = "stop";  //first strıng
String fastC = "fast";  //second strıng
String userC;   

switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            /*strıng array*/            
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            userC = Arrays.toString(result); //array convert to strıng.gıves error here.

            if(userC.compareTo(fastC)==0){   //compare coverted array wth strıng
                exam.speedUpBall();
                Toast.makeText(this, "fast!! =)",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

           else if (userC.compareTo(stopC)==0) {  
                exam.stop();
                Toast.makeText(this, "stop!! =)",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The error could be caused by an illegal argument. The Docs for [`Arrays.toString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[])) specify an `Object[]` argument, not `ArrayList`. Perhaps try `Arrays.toString(result.toArray())` ?

Comment: What data in your array?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Since I'm maybe just stupid: can you please explain to me where you see the equality of "Object[] -> String" (OPs question) and "Object[] -> String[]" (duplicate)?

Answer (score 3):

```
Arrays.toString()
```

method accepts arrays not `List`.

Comment: problem was that, so thanks.ı converted to arraylıst to strıng now

Answer (score 1):

The `toString()` of Java Arrays has to be applied on `Arrays`, and not for `ArrayList`.

So convert `ArrayList` to `Array`, then convert `Array` to `String`.

Try this code-

```
userC = result.toArray().toString();
```

It will work as expected :)

Comment: So you suggest to call `toString` on an array? You might want to give it a try, to see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to convert an ArrayList to String is by using [`TextUtils#join`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html):

```
userC = TextUtils.join("\t", result);
```

Comment: Please avoid posting stuff like "thank you" in your answer. I edited your answer a bit, to improve the text.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html),

```
toString(boolean[] a)
Returns a string representation of the contents of the specified array.
```

So the arguments should be only `arrays` e.g. `char[]`, `boolean[]`, `int[]` etc.

 `ArrayList` is not an array.

If you want to convert an `ArrayList` to `String`, you should build it yourself.
For example:

```
ArrayList<String> resultArrayList =  data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
String result = "";
for (String content: resultArrayList) {
    result += content;
}
```

Then you'll have a `String` that can be compared.
Also, take a look at this topic here in SO

[Best way to convert an ArrayList to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string)

Answer (score -2):

You need to first convert the List to array

```
ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<>();
String new_array=result.toArray().toString();
```

Comment: So you suggest to call `toString` on an array? You might want to give it a try, to see what you get.

Comment: thanks, found another way too, String userC = TextUtils.join("\t", result).  İt easily converts arraylist to strıng

Comment: @busrao You might want to add this approach as another answer for this question.