# pass arraylist via implicit intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I want to pass my arraylist via implicit intent just because I want to send my data in listview via whatsapp. Here is my code

```
public void save()
{

   ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(combination));


    Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");

    intent.putStringArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,arrayList);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

`save()` is a method that gets called when user presses SHARE button. But it actually doesn't pass anything to whatsapp.

Comment: Your name is awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate your strings together into one single string. Then, use that as your `EXTRA_TEXT` value. No application will be expecting an `ArrayList<String>` as the `EXTRA_TEXT` value, and so your existing code will not work.

Comment: @DhoniSingh: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string

Comment: String string= Arrays.toString(arrayList);   and then intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,string);  . This is what I have already tried . It works but give you a single line ...I want the actual list , not a line

Comment: @DhoniSingh: Well, the accepted answer on the question that I linked to shows joining them as separated by tabs. You are welcome to use `\n` instead of `\t` to join them by newlines. Since this is Android, you are also welcome to [use `TextUtils.join('\n', arrayList)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable%29), if you prefer. Expecting WhatsApp to do that work for you, though, is unrealistic.