# Need to customize arraylist values as below

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting array list output as below and i need to more customize it

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int j = 1 ; j<=5 ; j++){

String abcd = CustomKeywords.'nasdaqKeyword.AccessToRestoftheTable.navigatetogettablevaluerest'(Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(j));
     arrlist.add(abcd)   
}

System.out.println(arrlist);
```

Actual

[11/08/2019, $260.14, 17,520,500, $258.69, $260.44, $256.85, 11/07/2019, $259.43, 23,735,080, $258.74, $260.35, $258.11, 11/06/2019, $257.24, 18,966,120, $256.77, $257.49, $255.365, 11/05/2019, $257.13, 19,974,430, $257.05, $258.19, $256.32, 11/04/2019, $257.5, 25,817,950, $257.33, $257.845, $255.38, 11/01/2019, $255.82, 37,781,330, $249.54, $255.93, $249.16, 10/31/2019, $248.76, 34,790,520, $247.24, $249.17, $237.26, 10/30/2019, $243.26, 31,130,520, $244.76, $245.3, $241.21, 10/29/2019, $243.29, 35,709,870, $248.97, $249.75, $242.57, 10/28/2019, $249.05, 24,143,240, $247.42, $249.25, $246.72, 10/25/2019, $246.58, 18,369,300, $243.16, $246.73, $242.88, 10/24/2019, $243.58, 17,916,260, $244.51, $244.8, $241.805, 10/23/2019, $243.18, 19,932,550, $242.1, $243.24, $241.22, 10/22/2019, $239.96, 22,684,000, $241.16, $242.2, $239.6218, 10/21/2019, $240.51, 22,367,480, $237.52, $240.99, $237.32, 10/18/2019, $236.41, 24,377,170, $234.59, $237.58, $234.29, 10/17/2019, $235.28, 17,272,900, $235.09, $236.15, $233.52, 10/16/2019, $234.37, 19,286,690, $233.37, $235.24, $233.2, 10/15/2019, $235.32, 23,040,480, $236.39, $237.65, $234.88, 10/14/2019, $235.87, 24,413,480, $234.9, $238.1342, $234.6701, 10/11/2019, $236.21, 41,990,210, $232.95, $237.64, $232.3075, 10/10/2019, $230.09, 28,962,980, $227.93, $230.44, $227.3, 10/09/2019, $227.03, 19,029,420, $227.03, $227.79, $225.64, 10/08/2019, $224.4, 29,282,700, $225.82, $228.06, $224.33, 10/07/2019, $227.06, 30,889,270, $226.27, $229.93, $225.84, 10/04/2019, $227.01, 34,755,550, $225.64, $227.49, $223.89, 10/03/2019, $220.82, 30,352,690, $218.43, $220.96, $215.132, 10/02/2019, $218.96, 35,767,260, $223.06, $223.58, $217.93, 10/01/2019, $224.59, 36,187,160, $225.07, $228.22, $224.2, 09/30/2019, $223.97, 26,318,580, $220.9, $224.58, $220.79, 09/27/2019, $218.82, 25,361,290, $220.54, $220.96, $217.2814, 09/26/2019, $219.89, 19,088,310, $220, $220.94, $218.83, 09/25/2019, $221.03, 22,481,010, $218.55, $221.5, $217.1402, 09/24/2019, $217.68, 31,434,370, $221.03, $222.49, $217.19, 09/23/2019, $218.72, 19,419,650, $218.95, $219.84, $217.65, 09/20/2019, $217.73, 57,977,090, $221.38, $222.56, $217.473]

expected

```
    11/08/2019, $260.14, 17,520,500, $258.69, $260.44, $256.85,
    11/07/2019, $259.43, 23,735,080, $258.74, $260.35, $258.11,
    11/06/2019, $257.24, 18,966,120, $256.77, $257.49, $255.365,
    11/05/2019, $257.13, 19,974,430, $257.05, $258.19, $256.32,
    11/04/2019, $257.5, 25,817,950, $257.33, $257.845, $255.38,
    11/01/2019, $255.82, 37,781,330, $249.54, $255.93, $249.16,
    10/31/2019, $248.76, 34,790,520, $247.24, $249.17, $237.26,
.
.
.
```

please note that i need to remove [] also

Comment: convert arraylist to string. follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string

Comment: will check. thanks

Comment: one quick solution could be to convert everything in a string and break the `string `every time you encounter the 6th comma `(,)` .

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to split the string as per my expected outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is working for me.

```
String listString = String.join(", ", arrlist);
```

Answer (score 1):

To customize the *ArrayList* into the required format you need to convert it into a string and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.util.ArrayList;

  public class ConvertArrayList2Array {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
          arrlist.add("11/08/2019");
          arrlist.add("$260.14");
          arrlist.add("17,520,500");
          arrlist.add("$258.69");
          arrlist.add("$260.44");
          System.out.println(arrlist);
          String listString = "";
          for (String s : arrlist)
              listString += s + "\t";
          System.out.println(listString);
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [11/08/2019, $260.14, 17,520,500, $258.69, $260.44]
  11/08/2019  $260.14 17,520,500  $258.69 $260.44
  ```