# How to Extract only string using For-loop

Tags: for-loop, groovy

How to Extract only string using For loop.
For attached code:
**Expected Result**:
A0, A1, A2

**Actual Result**:
null, A0, A1, A2

```
def s = new String[3] 
s[0]="A0" 
s[1]="A1" 
s[2]="A2"  

def myString 
for(def i=0; i<s.size(); i++){ 
  str = s[i] 
  myString = myString + ", " + str 
} 

log.info "Final String: " +myString
```

Comment: Add log.info() inside your loop to debug and understand your bug

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to coding.
command 'def myString' is creating a 'null' in result, but I am not expecting null in my result. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, where text would do.  We can not search in
or copy from screenshots.

Comment: Can you please help how to extract only strings using For_loop. Below is my code:
**Expected Result:** A0, A1, A2
**Actual Result:** null, A0, A1, A2

`def s = new String[3]
s[0]="A0"
s[1]="A1"
s[2]="A2"

def myString
for(def i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
 str = s[i]
 myString = myString + ", " + str
}
log.info "Final String: " +myString`

Comment: Please edit the question next time and add the code there. Comments are a bad place for that.

Comment: As already stated: print `myString` inside the loop and you will see the problem. Yet this code is just `["a","b","c"].join(", ")`

Comment: myString would be null to begin with. Initialise it to an empty string

Comment: Thank you, but my requirement is to print the result (A0, A1, A2) using for-loop, please help me what I have done wrong in my above code ?

Comment: Thank you, I have initialised the myString as empty string, but my result is (,A0,A1,A2). The problem is I can see the Comma before 'A0' which is not my requirement. My Updated code is below:
`def s = new String[3]
s[0]="A0"
s[1]="A1"
s[2]="A2"

def myString=""
for(def i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
 str = s[i]
 myString = myString +","+ str
}
log.info "Final String: " +myString`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string