# How to store the Array List values in a String in java

Tags: java

```
List<WebElement> Applicationfor = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[contains(@id,'projectMainForm:projectTabSubview')]/li"));

// (I am capturing all the values that are there in the list with the above line)

List<String> applicationfor = new ArrayList<String>();

WebElement applicationfordropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[normalize-

space()='Application For*']/following::div[contains(@class,'ui-selectonemenu-trigger')][1]"));

// (I am clicking on the dropdown and fetching the values which is assigned to the ArrayLIST)

applicationfordropdown.click();


 Applicationfor.forEach(Ele -> applicationfor.add(Ele.getText()));

//System.out.println("Print the colvalues:"+applicationfor);

 for(String text : applicationfor)
 {
    System.out.println("Print the lst values:"+text);
 }
```

My question is if the applicationfor value is assigned to the Array List as seen in the above code it

prints only the first value in the list. where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is pure Java question, so please do not use other tags. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/599181/11270766

Comment: Are you sure that `Applicationfor` list has more than 1 element?

Comment: yes it has 11 values in the dropdown list