# Problem adding values stored as variables to a java list

Tags: java

I am going to create a list that I want to add elements to.  I have obtained the elements from clients via them completing 3 dialogue boxes indicating their preferences for a new car, and now I want to add these entries to the list.

I have declared my instance variables and here is the constructor for my list:

```
 public Car(String aMaker, String aModel, int aYearBuilt);
    {
        super();
        this.maker = aMaker;
        this.model = aModel;
        this.year = aYearBuilt;
    }
```

I have successfully put the return from my first client's dialogue boxes into 3 variables, created thus:

```
 String inputMaker;
 String inputModel;
 int inputYear;
```

(I remembered to use Integer.parseInt to convert the dialogue input string to an int).

Now I want to put the values in a list:

```
List<Car> newCarDetails = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

This is where I start to go wrong:

```
 newCarDetails.add(new Car(inputMaker, inputModel, inputYear));
    return newCarDetails;
```

Only I have clearly underestimated the task, because it doesn't work.  I just get a hashCode back.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you edit your code to be more readable please?

Comment: Sorry, new & not quite got the hang of it all yet.

Comment: `String input.Model;` isn't a valid variable declaration... what does your code actually look like?

Comment: It is not clear from your question where you are getting "hashCode". Could you add some more code that illustrates where you are seeing it?

Comment: I don't get it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry Jon, that was a typo that had crept in - fixed now.

Comment: @genobis - The items for the list have to be input from the client via a dialog box.  What I'm attempting is to then enter them into the list.  I thought assigning them each to a variable then adding them might work.

Comment: @Ellie: You haven't shown enough of your code to know what's going on - please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints. It's possible that my answer will already help, but it's worth knowing how to write a useful question for the future :)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make it succinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your output media is, but you could iterate over the list to format the output:

```
for (Car newCar : newCarDetails) {
  System.out.println("Make: " + newCar.getAMaker());
  System.out.println("Model: " + newCar.getAModel());
  System.out.println("Year: " + newCar.getAYearBuilt());
}
```

Alternatively, you could override Car's `toString()` method to regulate the formatting

```
class Car {
...

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(this.aMaker);
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append(this.aModel);
    sb.append(",");
    sb.append(this.aYearBuilt);
    sb.append(",");

    return sb.toString();
  }
}

...

for (Car newCar : newCarDetails) {
  System.out.println(newCar.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that possibility.

Comment: I added a method that is arguably better by overriding Car's toString() method.

Comment: Haha!  Those last 2 lines did it for me!  Thanks v much :) :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks fine to me. You're adding the new `Car` to a `List<Car>` that you've previously created. If by "hash code" you mean that when you do `System.out.println(newCarDetails)` you get some output like `<java.util.List<0x123456>>` that's just what happens when you try to print any class that doesn't have a `toString()` method. A lot of the Collections framework classes don't.

If you want to pretty-print it, [try the technique here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395401/printing-java-collections-nicely-tostring-doesnt-return-pretty-output).

Comment: Right.  That's very helpful.  As a complete novice I had assumed that what I'd written would return the 'String, string, int' input that had originally been in the 3 variables.  So it's likely that I'm not providing an appropriate toString() method.  Thank you, that gives me somewhere to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use a typed list:

```
List<Car> newCarDetails = new ArrayList<Car>();

newCarDetails.add(new Car(inputMaker, inputModel, inputYear));
```

Comment: Yes it was, it just wasn't in a code block, and HTML eats anything between `<` and `>` that isn't in a code block.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: You are correct, but because of this I wasn't able to see it initially.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually said what you're trying to do with the returned value, or how it's really behaving, only this:

> Only I have clearly underestimated the task, because it doesn't work. I just get a hashCode back. Any help greatly appreciated.

Hmm. My psychic debugging skills suggest that you're calling `toString` on either the `ArrayList<Car>` or the `Car` itself, and that's returning something which doesn't look terribly useful.

Options:

- Use the individual values within the `Car` when you're formatting (e.g. by calling the properties)
- Override `toString` in the `Car` class with your chosen format

If neither of those are useful, please edit your question to give more information about what you're doing with the list...