# Printing the stack values in Java

Tags: java, stack

In Java, I want to print the contents of a *Stack*. The `toString()` method prints them encased in square brackets delimited by commas: `[foo, bar, baz]`.

How do I get rid of them and print the variables only?

My code so far:

```
Stack myStack = new Stack ();

for(int j=0; j<arrayForVar.length; j++) {
    if(arrayForVar[j][1] != null) {
        System.out.printf("%s \n", arrayForVar[j][1] + "\n");
        myStack.push(arrayForVar[j][1]);
    }
}

System.out.printf("%s \n", myStack.toString());
```

**This answer worked for me:**

Use the `toString` method on the Stack, and use `replaceAll` method to replace all instances of square brackets with blankstring.  Like this:

```
System.out.print(
    myStack.toString().replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("]", ""));
```

Comment: I suspect half the code you have doesn't do what you want. Can you simplify your example? Why are you using a `Stack` at all?

Comment: Hi Lads, I appreciate everyone's help, i guess I found what i need, the answer to my question is as follows:        `System.out.print(myStack.toString().replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("]", ""));`

Comment: why you put // for [ and don't for ]?

Comment: Thanks Armani!  That helped me.  You should rewrite your update (to your question) as the answer and accept it.  Then I would up vote that too!

Answer (score 15):

There is a workaround.

You could convert it to an array and then print that out with `Arrays.toString(Object[])`:

`System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myStack.toArray()));`

Comment: its from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395401/printing-java-collections-nicely-tostring-doesnt-return-pretty-output

Answer (score 7):

```
stack.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Using Java 8 and later stream functions

Answer (score 3):

Use `toArray()` to print the stack values

```
public void printStack(Stack<Integer> stack) {

    // Method 1:
    String values = Arrays.toString(stack.toArray());
    System.out.println(values);

    // Method 2:
    Object[] vals = stack.toArray();
    for (Object obj : vals) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the same kind of loop that you used to fill the stack and print individual elements to your liking. There is no way to change the behavior of `toString`, except if you go the route of subclassing `Stack`, which I wouldn't recommend. If the source code of `Stack` is under your control, then just fix the implementation of `toString` there.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is the `join` method of String which is similar to the join method of Python:

```
"" + String.join("/", stack)
```

This will return the string containing all the elements of the stack and we can also add some delimiter by passing in the first argument.

Example: Stack has two elements [home, abc]

Then this will return "/home/abc".

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of toString() method of `AbstractCollection`. So you can not do it unless you define your own `Stack`Or implement custom toString() by iterating over `Stack`

**public String toString()**

> Returns a string representation of this collection. The string representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets ("[]"). Adjacent elements are separated by the characters ", " (comma and space). Elements are converted to strings as by String.valueOf(Object).
>
> This implementation creates an empty string buffer, appends a left square bracket, and iterates over the collection appending the string representation of each element in turn. After appending each element except the last, the string ", " is appended. Finally a right bracket is appended. A string is obtained from the string buffer, and returned.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a suggestion into the pool here. Depending on your Stack implementation this may or may not be possible.

The suggestion is an anonymous inner class for overriding the toString() in this particular case. This is one way to locally implement the subclassing Marko is mentioning. Your Stack instantiation would look something like

```
Stack s = new Stack(){
              public String toString(){
                 // query the elements of the stack, build a string and
                 return nicelyFormattedString;
              }
          };
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!myStack.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print(myStack.pop());
}
```

You will print the first element of the stack and pop it, repeating until the stack is empty

Comment: Thou this works,
 it also removes the values in the stack which might not be what users would be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using string builder

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder()
while(!myStack.isEmpty())result.append(myStack.pop());
System.out.print(result.reverse().toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we like imagining the stack from ***top to bottom***, I felt this would be helpful to print a stack *without losing the values in the stack* :)

```
public void printStack(Stack<Integer> s) {
    System.out.print("------ stack start ------\n");
    printStackRecursion(s);
    System.out.print("------ stack end ------\n\n");
}

public void printStackRecursion(Stack<Integer> s) {
    if (s.empty()) return;
    int x = s.peek();
    s.pop();
    System.out.println(x);
    printStackRecursion(s);
    s.push(x);
}
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-stack-elements-from-top-to-bottom/

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.asList(stackobject.toArray()));
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stackobject.toArray()));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code and explain a little bit because this answers the question.

Answer (score -3):

```
 Stack <String> Cars=new Stack();
 Cars.push("Lambo Urus");
    Cars.push("Honda Civic");
    Cars.push("Ford Mustang");

   while(!Cars.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(Cars.pop());
            }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.