# How to print a stack in Java

Tags: java, stack, queue

I wrote a method that receives a *queue* as a parameter and then convert this queue into a stack. Now I want to try to print this method in the main to see if it works, but there isn't any toString method for stacks.

I already did some research and tried to convert stacks into arrays, but I can't get it to work. [Printing the stack values in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160183/printing-the-stack-values)

How can I do this?

```
public static void QueueStack(Queue<Integer> q){
    Stack<Integer> stack1 = new Stack<Integer>();
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        int temp = q.dequeue();
        stack1.push(temp);
    }
    Arrays.toString(stack1.toArray());
}
```

Comment: Why dont you want to use System.out.println(stack1) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/395403/1980659

Comment: @BatScream I thought I couldn't use Syso for stacks (I learned stacks using arrays and had to write a for to print the values), now I know I can use it to print them out.

Comment: user stack1.addAll(q) instead of looping the Queue

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the Stack classes' toString() method?

e.g.

```
stack1.toString();
```

Or was there a specific format you want to print out?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [`get(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#get(int)) method of the `Vector` class which `Stack` extends, assuming you don't want to pop the elements from your stack while you print them.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it very similar to how to initialized it.

```
while(!stack1.isEmpty())
{
   int t = stack1.pop();
   System.out.println(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!tack1.isEmpty()) {
    for(Object a : stack1) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, is a method to convert a given Queue to Stack:

```
public static void QueueStack(Queue<Integer> queue){

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    for(Integer in: queue){
        stack.push(in);
    }
    //Here, the output would be same as you inserted elements.As stack uses iterator which prints elements as they are inserted(a bug in stack iteration)
    System.out.println("Stack: "+stack);
    
    //You can use java 8 for-each style as well.
    stack.forEach(System.out::println);
    
    //If you want to traverse stack in LIFO manner..
    while(stack.isEmpty){
    System.ou.println(stack.pop());
    }
    
    //For better performance ArrayDeque<>() is preferred!
    Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
    
}
```