# How to show the contents of each stack from top to bottom?

Tags: java, stack

I want to output the contents of each stack after the code below has executed. so far its outputting as

```
Stack@568db2f2
Stack@378bf509
Stack@378bf509
```

but I want the contents of each stack.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack<Integer> a = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Integer> b = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Integer> c = new Stack<>();

    a.push(28);
    b.push(a.pop());
    b.peek();
    c.push(21);
    a.push(14);
    a.peek();
    b.push(c.pop());
    c.push(7);
    b.push(a.pop());
    b.push(c.pop());

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
    System.out.println(b);

}
```

Comment: If you don't need the stacks to still be filled at the end of the program you can `pop` one element at a time (until the stack is empty) and print it.

Comment: what type of output you are expecting for contents of each stack ? `String` [28, 21, 14, 7] ?

Comment: @aKilleR would they all end up empty?

Comment: @EGS99 , Will not be empty if you use `peek()` Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160183/java-printing-the-stack-values) out

Answer (score 0):

[`Stack<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html) is a subclass of [`Vector<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html), which you can use [`.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html#size()) and [`.elementAt(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Vector.html#elementAt(int)) on:

```java
Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
stack.push("!");
stack.push("world");
stack.push(" ");
stack.push("Hello");
for (int i = stack.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  System.out.print(i);
}
System.out.println();
```

As Federico pointed out however, if you don't care about emptying the stacks when printing them, then you can also just loop over them calling `.pop()` until they are empty.

However, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524949/1406083) points out, you should be using a [`Deque<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) instead of a `Stack<E>`. [`LinkedList<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements `Deque<E>`, and can easily be iterated over to print its elements (from top to bottom):

```java
Deque<String> stack = new LinkedList<String>();
stack.push("!");
stack.push("world");
stack.push(" ");
stack.push("Hello");
for (String item : stack) {
  System.out.print(item);
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the default `toString()` for the class `Stack` prints the stack's location in the memory or something like that instead of printing the stack's contents. You should use the following code for each stack (stk is the original Stack taht you want to print its contents):

```
//Create another temporary Stack
Stack<Integer> temp = new Stack<>();

//Print each content of the original Stack (stk) separately.
//Move each content to the temporary Stack (temp), in order to preserve it.
while(! stk.empty())
   {
       System.out.println(stk.peek());
       temp.push(stk.pop());
   }

//Move all the content back to the original Stack (stk)
while(! temp.empty())
   {
       stk.push(temp.pop());
   }
```