# Can a Java List be output as a String?

Tags: java, list

If I want to print the string "Output:" followed by whatever result a method returns, the only one that will do so on the same line as "Output:" is a method that returns a String type.  For instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println(returnString("Hello"));
}

public static String returnString(String s){
    return "Output:" + s;
}
```

If, however, I want to print the string "Output:" followed by the method return of any other variable type, the return would have to be on a separate line. For instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println(returnInt(2));
}

 pubic static int returnInt(int n){
  System.out.println("Output:");
  return n;
}
```

or by changing the return type to String and using a built-in conversion method that is appropriate for the return type. For instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println(returnInt(2));
}

public static String returnInt(int n){
  return "Output:" + String.valueOf(n)
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println(returnArray(new int[]{1, 2, 3}));
}

public static String returnArray(int[] array){
  return "Output:" + Arrays.toString(array);
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println(returnBoolean(false));
}

 public static String returnBoolean(boolean b){
  return "Output:" + Boolean.toString(b);
}
```

So three questions:

1) It's not possible to declare two return types when initializing a method the same way you can declare two input types (i.e. methodName(int n, String S)), correct?

2) Is there any way (such as an escape sequence) that pulls the next line up ot the same line when returning a non-string?

2) And if not, is there a built-in method for returning a List (the way Arrays.toString or String.value Of do for their respective types?  I can't find anything similar such as List.ToString etc.

Comment: You're misunderstanding output and the result (or return value) of a method invocation.

Comment: Also, look into String concatenation.

Comment: Just use `System.out.print` without `ln`

Comment: @Ingo.  thanks. that was short and sweet lol.  So there's no way to allow two return types in sequence or a List conversion method like Arrays.toString, correct?

Comment: What do you mean returning two types in a sequence?

Comment: @StuartKuredjian You can just return one value. But, of course, this value can be a tuple.

Comment: @mrres1 I think this was answered by someone else defining an object. But I was asking if its possible for one method to return say, an int and then a String.

Comment: Nope, can't do that in Java.  Check out Ruby, Python, or other languages that will pack/unpack tuples for you automatically.

Comment: @StuartKuredjian OK, then yes, as everyone is talking about, you are referring to a tuple.  Java does not have these.   http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/tuples.html

Answer (score 2):

1) That's correct. A method could return an object that contained instance variables of multiple types, though.

2) If you use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()` it will not add a newline at the end.

3) [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/395403/754604) provides a simple way to print out the elements of a List.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stack.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 2):

In java you can always write the following:

```
Object o = someMethod();
System.out.println("Output: " + o);
```

The JVM will implicitly call `o.toString()` to convert it to a string and then append it to the string 'Output: '.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) It's not possible to declare two return types when initializing a method the same way you can declare two input types (i.e. methodName(int n, String S)), correct?

Correct, in Java, if you want to return multiple things, you should make an object that represents the data you're returning, and return that.  So instead of returning paws, head, body, legs and a tail object, you'd return a `Dog`.

> 2) Is there any way (such as an escape sequence) that pulls the next line up ot the same line when returning a non-string?

You bet, just don't tell it to add a newline.  That's what [println](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) is doing for you, it means "print line".  Instead, just use [print](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29).

> 2) And if not, is there a built-in method for returning a List (the way Arrays.toString or String.value Of do for their respective types? I can't find anything similar such as List.ToString etc.

Most List implementations will have a toString method, so you can definitely print them out, try it.  It may not be exactly what you want, so you may have to write a helper method to format it how you're intending.

Comment: @ Nick Veys I tried that.  That's what led to this whole post in the first place lol.  neither List.toString() nor ArrayList.toString() work. ArrayList.toString errors with "The method toString() in the type AbstractCollection is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)" and using List.toString() errors with "The method toString() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)"

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're doing wrong, but here's a simple example of printing a list: http://pastebin.com/r8CtKTy4

Comment: Are you actually calling a method like `List.toString(some_list)`?  Because that's not going to work.  List is an interface, you can't call methods on it directly, and the `toString` is actually on the objects themselves and is called automatically when coerced into a String.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this all wrong.

> If I want to print the string "Output:" followed by whatever result a
>   method returns, the only one that will do so on the same line as
>   "Output:" is a method that returns a String type.

Absolutely not.

Take this method

```
public int returnAnInt() {
    return 42;
}
```

You can print the value returned by this method like so

```
System.out.println("Output:" + /*possibleInstance.*/returnAnInt());
```

This is possible due to [`String` concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753869/how-do-i-concatenate-two-strings-in-java).

Don't write your methods with output in mind. For example, if you have a method that is supposed to calculate the sum of two integers

```
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Just make it calculate the sum of two integers.

There's no need to put the output in the method itself. Make the code that calls this method output the value

```
int sum = add(16, 27);
System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
// or
System.out.println("The sum is: " + add(16, 27));
```

As to your 3 questions, which I think become rather moot, see the other answers. [You might want to look at the `toString()` method which all reference types inherit.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class tst
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(toString(1));
        System.out.println(toString("hello"));
        System.out.println(toString(false));
        System.out.println(toString(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
    }

    static String toString(Object object)
    {
        return "Output: (" + object.getClass().getSimpleName() + ") " + object;
    }
}
```

The console output is:

```
Output: (Integer) 1
Output: (String) hello
Output: (Boolean) false
Output: (Integer[]) [Ljava.lang.Integer;@51de8adb
```

Comment: Extremely lousy solution.